# Inner query inside select in laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, inner-query

How can I place inner query inside a select statement in laravel query builder.
I want to convert following mysql query in to laravel query builder

```
select i1.client_id,count(*),(
    select SUM((ii.quantity*ii.rate))as total 
    from invoice_items ii 
    join invoices i on i.id = ii.invoice_id
    where i.client_id =i1.client_id)as sale
from invoices i1
group by i1.client_id
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to add overhead? Simple execute it as a raw statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can create you query like with laravel query builder

```
DB::select(DB::raw("i1.client_id,count(*),(
    select SUM((ii.quantity*ii.rate))as total 
    from invoice_items ii 
    join invoices i on i.id = ii.invoice_id
    where i.client_id =i1.client_id)as sale"))
->from('from invoices i1')
->groupBy('i1.client_id');
```

hope this will work for you.